# Switched to Django 1.8 and ImportError at / No module named forms

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I have a custom login page with custom login form. This code worked in Django 1.6.6. But when I upgraded to Django 1.8 I start getting ImportError at /
No module named forms. If I remove my custom authentication_form and password_reset_form it "works".

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import url

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from users.forms import PlayingAuthenticationForm, PlayingPasswordResetForm
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^logga-in/$',
                           "users.views.login",
                           {'extra_context': {'facebook_redirect_uri': settings.FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI, 'google_redirect_uri': settings.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI, }, 'template_name': 'registration/login.html', 'authentication_form': PlayingAuthenticationForm},
                           name='auth_login'),
                       url(r'^logga-ut/$',
                           auth_views.logout,
                           {'template_name': 'registration/logout.html'},
                           name='auth_logout'),
                       url(r'^byt-losenord/$',
                           auth_views.password_change,
                           name='password_change'),
                       url(r'^byt-losenord/klar/$',
                           auth_views.password_change_done,
                           name='password_change_done'),
                       url(r'^glomt-losenord/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset,
                           {'password_reset_form': PlayingPasswordResetForm },
                           name='password_reset'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
                           name='password_reset_confirm'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset_complete,
                           name='password_reset_complete'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset_done,
                           name='password_reset_done'),
)
```

It should work, right? I can't find anything wrong with importing forms and the forms.py is still in the users app.

Edit: Complete traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'adminforum',
 'common',
 'social',
 'forums',
 'localflavor',
 'mailsender',
 'menu',
 'notifications',
 'pm',
 'users',
 'registration')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'users.middleware.UserMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  119.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  366.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  402.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  396.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "C:\playing\playing_se\urls.py" in <module>
  24.     url(r'^medlem/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py" in include
  33.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "C:\playing\apps\registration\backends\default\urls.py" in <module>
  78.                        (r'', include('registration.auth_urls')),
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py" in include
  33.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "C:\playing\apps\registration\auth_urls.py" in <module>
  31. from users.forms import PlayingAuthenticationForm, PlayingPasswordResetForm

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named forms
```

And my forms.py:

```
from django.forms.models import ModelForm
from django import forms
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from users.models import GENDER_CHOICES, UserProfile
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
from django.forms.widgets import FileInput
from localflavor.se.forms import SEPostalCodeField
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, PasswordResetForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from flanker.addresslib import address

class HorizRadioRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
    """ this overrides widget method to put radio buttons horizontally
        instead of vertically.
    """
    def render(self):
            """Outputs radios"""
            return mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'%s\n' % w for w in self]))

class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    gender = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer,
                                 choices=GENDER_CHOICES), required=False, label="Kön")
    birthday = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1900, 2012)), required=False, label="Födelsedatum")
    description = forms.CharField(label="Presentation", required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'maxlength': 530}))
    zipcode = SEPostalCodeField(label="Postnummer", required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['description', 'gender', 'birthday', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'zipcode', 'city' ]

class UserAvatarForm(ModelForm):
    avatar_image = forms.ImageField(widget=FileInput, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['avatar_image',]
        exclude = ['avatar']

class PlayingAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label=_("Username"), max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Användarnamn', 'autofocus':'autofocus'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Lösenord'}))
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(initial=True, required=False)

class PlayingPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        if not get_user_model().objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data['email']):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Det finns inget användarkonto kopplat till den e-postadressen.")
        return self.cleaned_data['email']

class UserEmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if get_user_model().objects.filter(email__iexact=data):
            raise forms.ValidationError("E-postadressen är redan upptagen. Försök med en annan.")
        valid_email = address.validate_address(data)
        if not valid_email:
            raise forms.ValidationError("E-postadressen felaktig. Försök med en annan.")
        return data
```

Comment: show the complete traceback

Comment: @joelgoldstick Updated with traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. I removed 'authentication_form': PlayingAuthenticationForm in my auth_urls.py and added authentication_form=PlayingAuthenticationForm in my custom view instead.